# Big Oh notation of two non nested loops

Tags: big-o

This is my question and I've managed to bring out an answer for part a, but for part b I'm not really confident about my answer of part b.

In a recent court case, a judge cited a city for contempt and ordered a ﬁne of $2 for the ﬁrst day. 
Each subsequent day, until the city followed the judge’s order, the ﬁne was squared 
(i.e., the ﬁne progressed as follows: $2, $4, $16, $256, $65,536,...). 
a. What would be the ﬁne on day N? 
b. How many days would it take for the ﬁne to reach D dollars (a Big-Oh answer will do)?

Ans a : 2^(2^n-1)

For answer b, I made the following program to find the big Oh.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    result = 2 * result;
}
printf("%d\t", result);

for (int j = 0; j < result; j++) {
    res = 2 * res ;
}
printf("%d\n", res);
```

I have calculated the big Oh of the first loop to be Sumation of n
And since the second loop runs 2^n-1 times the first loop, its big Oh is 2^n and adding them both they become (2^n) + n

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need any software to answer these questions. Big O is a math term that happens to be used in software development.

Let's look at the progression:

```
2     = 2^1  = 2^(2^0)
4     = 2^2  = 2^(2^1)
16    = 2^4  = 2^(2^2)
256   = 2^8  = 2^(2^3)
65536 = 2^16 = 2^(2^4)
```

**Answer to question a.**

The penalty on day `n` would be `2^(2^(n-1))`.

You could program it like this:

```
pow(2, pow(2, n-1));
```

**Answer to question b.**

```
x = log2 (log2 D) + 1
```

Or without the "+ 1" if we're not to count the first day.
This will return a positive real number, so you may want to ceil it depending on the requirements.

Now, in big O notation, it would be O(log(log)), which describes how the value grows. What that means is that when the input (D in this case) is multiplied by `n`, the value of the function will increase by at most `log(log n)` times.

Answer (score 1):

According to my algorithm my answer is O(N)

```
int days=5;
int fine = 2;
for(int i=0; i<days-1; i++)
   fine =  fine * fine;

cout << fine;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first loop runs `n-1` times, the second runs `2^(n-1)` times. The time-complexity
is the sum of these so `(n-1) + 2^(n-1) = O(2^n + n) = O(2^n)`.

The question doesn't seem to be asking for the time-complexity though. It's asking
how many days would pass before the fine reaches D dollars. This is the inverse of
the answer to a): `O(log log D)` ($65536 is reached after `log(log(65536)) + 1` days, for example).